# SimpleMembership Demands App_Data Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm using SimpleMembership for an ASP.Net MVC 4 application.

The connection string is configured to use SQL Server rather than LocalDB in both development and production.  That works fine, except that in production, where there is no App_Data folder, SimpleMembership attempts to access App_Data on the first HTTP request to the site after the app pool is recycled (consistently reproducible).  For subsequent HTTP requests, it does not attempt to access App_Data.

If I pre-create App_Data and grant read/write permissions, the error is not raised.  No files are created in App_Data.

Is there something I can configure (short of creating a dummy App_Data folder in production) to prevent this "dummy" access attempt?

The stack trace for reference:

```
2013-02-04 21:10:27.4133 FATAL Global Exception.  Status 500, Message: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\MyWebApp\App_Data' is denied.
2013-02-04 21:10:28.5643 ERROR    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureDBFile(String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
   at System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy the line starting with "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(...)" in InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs to the beginning of Application_Start method in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyDBContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth(); 
}
```